# How to refresh all TOCs via a script?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, table-of-contents

I would like a script to update all tables of content in my document. I tried

```
var t = app.activeDocument.tocStyles;  
for (var i=0; i<t.length; i++) {   
  app.activeDocument.createTOC(t[i],true);  
}
```

as suggested [here](https://forums.adobe.com/message/3815908#3815908), but for those TOC styles I do not uses it creates a new story. So, how can I figure out whether a TOC style is actually used? I know I can loop over all stories and check whether their `storyType` is [`StoryTypes.TOC_STORY`](http://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign11/#StoryTypes.html), but I haven't figured out how to determine *which* TOC style that story then uses or how to refresh specifically that story. I even considered using

```
app.menuActions.item("$ID/UpdateTableOfContentsCmd").invoke();
```

which would just use the menu action (which sounds like something to avoid), but in that case I fail due to the action being inactive - I must change the selection somehow first, but `app.select(story)` fails due to an invalid data type...

Comment: This might be off topic for graphic design as its a script question. You might have better luck getting an answer on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Lex I've seen more helpful scripting answers here than on SO. I'd have asked there if the question were more about JavaScript itself, but this is more a question of the InDesign API

Comment: Still, in questions not to ask "Application Troubleshooting questions or other forms of technical support". I think it would fall under off topic (other scripting questions too, not this one specifically)

Comment: @Lex Then what's the point of the [tag:indesign-scripting] tag? I'm not asking for troubleshooting or technical support.

Comment: But it is another form of technical support :p Its good point about the indesign-scripting tag... Anyway I'm not flagging it off topic, I hope you get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's my "solution" so far, unfortunately relying on using `menuActions`:

```
function updateTOCs() {
    var stories = app.activeDocument.stories;
    for(var i=0; i < stories.length; i++) {
        var story = stories[i]
        if(story.storyType != StoryTypes.TOC_STORY)
            continue;
        story.textContainers[0].select()
        app.menuActions.item("$ID/UpdateTableOfContentsCmd").invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that, at this date (almost 3 years passed!) this is the only way to do that. Thank you for sharing your solution.If only Adobe updated its scripting engine... :/

Comment: @GabrielRambaud Thanks, it's comforting to hear I'm not alone with this 